# Left recursion elimination in an LL1 grammar

Tags: java, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, javacc

I'm trying to eliminate left recursion from the following extract of a grammar -

```
expression := fragment ( ( + | - | * | / )  fragment )*

fragment := identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | expression
```

The issue is that expression can go to fragment, can go to expression. I've tried a bunch of ways to eliminate it, some look like they work (in JavaCC) but I'm a)unsure of their correctness, and b) pretty sure I've broken associativity by changing the structure of the grammar.

I'm pretty sure I need an expression', and have

```
fragment := identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | expression
```

changed to

```
fragment := identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | expressionPrime
```

But I'm unsure of the way to form expressionPrime. Both

```
expressionPrime := identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | {}
```

And

```
expressionPrime := ( ( + | - | * | / )  fragment )*
```

Seem to work, but I know it can't be both.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, even a point in the right direction.

Comment: There are well-documented methods for removing left recursion: what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you think you need `expression` in `fragment` at all?

Comment: Changed the question to reflect what I've tried. Part of the problem I'm having is the wording, examples I've read use productions like 
A -> Ab |c to illustrate, but I'm finding it very difficult to link the parts of the grammar above to their respective parts in the tutorials.

Comment: user2357112, its a grammar we've been set, we can change it if we can make a case for the change. Would it not fundamentally change what the grammar could accept if I just removed expression from fragment?

Comment: Yep. And because that's too short to be a comment, double yep.

Comment: It looks to me as if there are missing parenthesis tokens around  `expresssion`. I.e. `fragment ::= ... | "(" expression ")"`. I suggest going back to your instructor and asking if there is something missing.

Comment: I don't think there is anything missing, but he probably has it deliberately worded difficulty, I know I'm having trouble making sense of it. I asked someone today, they said I need to introduce associativity which also removes the recursion. If I figure it out and no one has answered I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
expression ::= fragment ( ( + | - | * | / )  fragment )*
fragment ::= identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | expression
```

Define

```
frag1 ::= identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment
```

Note that fragment is equivalent to `frag1 | expression`. Replace the former by the latter everywhere to get

```
expression ::= (frag1 | expression) ( ( + | - | * | / )  (frag1 | expression) )*
frag1 ::= identifier | number | ( + | - ) (frag1 | expression)
```

`fragment` is no longer needed.

Distribute to get

```
expression ::= frag1 more | expression more   ,
```

where

```
more ::= ( ( + | - | * | / )  (frag1 | expression) )*
```

Now you can see that an expression is a `frag1` followed by one or more `more`

So

```
expression ::= frag1 (more)+
```

Your grammar is still ambiguous -- there are 2 parse tress for "1 * - 2 * 3". But at least it is not left recursive anymore.

(If you use this in your assignment, be sure to cite this answer, so you don't end up breaking your institution's academic dishonesty rules.)

I still think your instructor made a mistake, since, if you change

```
fragment ::= identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | expression
```

to

```
fragment ::= identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | "(" expression ")"   ,
```

you have a sensible grammar for expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've emailed the instructor re the "(" and ")" and will see what he says. For the moment I've gone with redefining expression and fragment as expresion / term / factor, which I think define the same grammar - 
expression ::= term expressionPrime
expressionPrime ::= + expression | - expression | {}
term ::= factor termPrime
termPrime ::= * term | / term | {}
factor ::= number | id
Would this accept the same input?

Comment: If you add in unary operators, I think it would.  Also you are now handling precedence of * and / over + and -, which is likely the right thing to do.

Comment: Whereabouts do you think I should put the unary operators? I had to hack around a bit because his example files for us to parse include modulo (%) operator. I was considering defining a non terminal unary() and adding the operators to it, but unsure whether to put them in term or factor

Comment: It depends what their precedence is.